# awk column spliting using delimitter

Tags: text-processing, gawk

I want to split the first column into two, so that the output look like

```
00400000    00401000
```

I have an input file like this

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2762331                           
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:05 2762331                           
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 2762331                            
00f70000-00f91000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

I have used this code

```
awk  '{print $1,$2}' FS="-" filename
```

but its giving output

```
00400000 00401000 r
00600000 00601000 r
00601000 00602000 rw
00f70000 00f91000 rw
7f70f2399000 7f70f2558000 r
```

Comment: With a very limitted knowledge i was not able to get the output.. i was asking how to get the required  output

Comment: You could have set `FS` to whitespace *or* hyphen: `FS="[ \t]+|-"`

Comment: awk -FS="[ \t]+|-" '{print $1,$2}' filename . No this dosent worked

Comment: That's different from what I suggested - it would set `FS` to `S="[ \t]+|-"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just perform simple substitution under the 1st field:

```
awk '{ sub("-", FS, $1); print $1 }' filename
```

The output:

```
00400000 00401000
00600000 00601000
00601000 00602000
00f70000 00f91000
```

Comment: awk '{ sub("-", FS, $1); print $1 }' filename . This one is more refined

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the result by below command

---

```
 awk -F "-" '{print $1,$2}' filename  | awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

---

Output

```
00400000 00401000
00600000 00601000
00601000 00602000
00f70000 00f91000
```